# How would I display a TIFF images in all web browsers?

Tags: html, image, tiff

How do I handle [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) images in HTML pages?

I have tried using the embed tag, object id, img, etc. But, I am unable to display the TIFF image in the HTML page.

I am not using Java, .NET, or any other alternatives in my project.

**UPDATE:** Safari supports TIFF image loading. How can I load TIFF images in other browsers (IE, Mozilla, Firefox, etc.)?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This comes down to browser image support; it looks like the only mainstream browser that supports tiff is Safari:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Where are you getting the tiff images from? Is it possible for them to be generated in a different format?

If you have a static set of images then I'd recommend using something like [PaintShop Pro](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/gb/en/Product/1184951547051) to batch convert them, changing the format.

If this isn't an option then there might be some mileage in looking for a pre-written Java applet (or another browser plugin) that can display the images in the browser.

Comment: +1 TIFF in browsers is an unsure thing - even more so with CMYK ones. I suggest conveting to JPG or PNG.

Comment: I kept TIFF images in local system only. As per the specification, i should not convert into another format.

Comment: As per the Image format support in Browser, i can use safari to display the TIFF image. Is it right?

Comment: @ashok: The Wikipedia page claims that Safari can render TIFF images. I'd recommend downloading it (assuming you're using Windows) and trying it out.

http://www.apple.com/safari/download/

Comment: I would convert to PNG (that way you don't have to lose detail like in JPG... plus you are going to massively reduce the filesize you are serving up to the client.  XnView provides awesome conversion utilities if you need a free app.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Thanks to every one to support me.
I could load TIFF image in safari browser

Comment: Chrome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/inline-tiff-viewer/kkfncbfgbghoklckdmeljdjohpkknlma

Answer (score 17):

I found this resource that details the various methods: [How to embed TIFF files in HTML documents](http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html)

As mentioned, it will very much depend on browser support for the format. Viewing that page in Chrome on Windows didn't display any of the images.

It would also be helpful if you posted the code you've tried already.

Comment: Sorry it would be very large. So i am posting image loading part only
1)

<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%"  
CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">  
<PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="tiffdocument.tif">  
<PARAM name="SCALE" VALUE="aspect">  
</OBJECT> 


2)

<img width=200 height=200 
  src="tiffdocument.tif" alt="">

like that

Comment: It doesn't work in the recent Chrome as it says: _This site uses a plugin (image/tiff) that is unsupported_.

Answer (score 4):

Tiff images can be displayed directly onto IE and safari only.. no support of tiff images on chrome and firefox. you can encode the image and then display it on browser by decoding the encoded image to some other format.
Hope this works for you

Comment: Can you include any source, in case this information becomes outdated?

Answer (score 4):

You can try converting your image from tiff to PNG, here is how to do it:

```java
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageCodec;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageDecoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.ImageEncoder;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.PNGEncodeParam;
import com.sun.media.jai.codec.TIFFDecodeParam;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javaxt.io.Image;

public class ImgConvTiffToPng {
 
    public static byte[] convert(byte[] tiff) throws Exception {

        byte[] out = new byte[0];
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(tiff);

        TIFFDecodeParam param = null;

        ImageDecoder dec = ImageCodec.createImageDecoder("tiff", inputStream, param);
        RenderedImage op = dec.decodeAsRenderedImage(0);

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        PNGEncodeParam jpgparam = null;
        ImageEncoder en = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("png", outputStream, jpgparam);
        en.encode(op);
        outputStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) en.getOutputStream();
        out = outputStream.toByteArray();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        return out;

    }
}
```

Comment: from where can I download `com.sun.media.jai.codec`? I tried to look for it over the web and there was no JAR

Comment: @roeygol It comes from the discontinued Java Advanced Imaging SDK at https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#jai-1_1_2_01-oth-JPR