# Using a Tiff image on a webpage

Tags: asp.net

I may be forced into using a tiff image on a webpage.

Do most modern browsers handle tiffs. Are there any gotchas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Safari, you're good... otherwise, good luck
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Here is some further reading using the AlternaTiff (workaround)
http://www.alternatiff.com/
http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html

However, since you're using ASP.NET, maybe you can convert the Tiff to a Jpg in the backend
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/dotnet_convertimage.aspx
http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/267798-convert-tiff-images-gif-jpeg

<sub>reference this [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser)</sub>

Comment: Personally I rock the PNG's as much as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Browsers don't do tiff generally. However [alternatif](http://www.alternatiff.com/) is a pretty good and free solution for displaying tiffs.

You might also consider converting the tiff to somethings else on the back end and on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

I was given a similar requirement, and solved it by converting the TIFF into a JPEG server-side and then supplying the option to ZOOM, at which point I would obtain a larger copy.

There is limited browser support for TIFF files and they tend to be more much, much larger than the equivalent JPEG.