# Why are .tif images not used in webpages (TIF cannot be used in internet browsers)?

Tags: drupal-6, tiff

I am using Image file cck field in my Drupal 6 site and the field doesnt let me use .tif images. I even tried configuring the field but it doesnt let me add .tif in the Permitted upload file extensions field. I found many links that say TIF cannot be used in internet browsers. I just want to know why??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser

Comment: Thnx for the link...It was helpful!!

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with TIFF support is that each additional graphics format to be supported by the browsers has to be maintained. Which would be a pain especially in case of TIFF, which has several different versions and seems a bit hard to implement right. The implementation and maintenace cost would not offset the advantages (are there any?), which is why [almost no browser supports it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991).

Answer (score 0):

You can use tiff images but not all browsers can display them. Used to be that only Safari supported tiffs, I'm not sure if any major vendor implemented this recently.