# Problem in time to show images

Tags: html, css, uiimageview

I need to show pictures of direfentes formats such as JPG, GIF, BMP, TIF, PNG, PCX, but I'm not getting the images in tif and pcx formats appear in the html image tag, anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: Why would you want to show image formats like tif on a web page? They are very large file and will take forever to download on user's machine. JPG and GIF are the best options as they are compressed to a much smaller size acceptable for web viewing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers can't display TIFF and afaik no browser can display PCX images, using standard `<img>` tags.

A solution would be to convert the image to a supported format, either manually or automatically (using php or server-side language).

Answer (score 1):

The img tag can only handle jpg, gif, bmp and png files. To display i.e. a tiff file you can use the embed tag.

```
<embed width=xxx height=xxx src="tiffdocument.tif" type="image/tiff">
```

[More variations here](http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html)

Answer (score 0):

Repeat of: [Display TIFF image in all web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser). It's browser support issue.