# TIFF format not working with CSS

Tags: css, tiff, gif

The image (logo.tiff) will not display when defined in the CSS file and called in the Index file.

However, when I save it in another format, such as gif or jpeg, it works just fine. Is there a reason or a workaround for this?

Thanks guys.

CSS file:

```
.logo{
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    background:url(../images/logo.tiff) no-repeat;
    width:218px;
    height:103px;
}
```

Index.html file:

```
<h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Our Slogan Here</a></h1>
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser)

Answer (score 5):

TIF files re not supported in Web Browsers

Comment: Jeez, I had no idea =/ Haha, there you go. Sorry about the question then!

Comment: PNG or JPEG are pretty much your only options (PNG generally replaces GIF).