# Can't stream tiff image using cfcontent

Tags: image, coldfusion, streaming

We're using cfcontent to stream images from outside the web root. jpegs, pngs, and gifs all stream correctly, but I can't get any tiff files to stream. I get the broken image icon, even though I can see that the file is in the correct location and the file name is stored correctly and is being passed correctly.

The code is really simple - the displaying page has

```
 <img src="?file=common/includes/displayPhoto.cfm&thisImage=someImage.tiff" />
```

and displayPhoto.cfm has

```
<cfcontent type = "image/*" file = "#imagePath#" deleteFile = "No">
```

where #imagePath# has the fully qualified file path.

I'm at a loss - and my friend Google has let me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably doing it right. The problem is that *most browsers do not support TIFF*. The only browser that does (and not all TIFF formats, at that!) is Safari.

On Firefox, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Opera etc, you will always see the broken image icon - because to the browser that image is indeed "broken", unintelligible.

See also [Display TIFF image in all web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser)

Comment: I guess those requirements are going to have to be changed :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is wrong actually: You have something.cfm&x=y. In URL's, you begin with a question mark: something.cfm?x=y.

Comment: His URL is `?file=common/includes/displayPhoto.cfm&thisImage=someImage.tiff` which is (URL-wise) valid, if rather an unusual way of doing it.

Comment: Oh lord - sorry. My eyes totally missed that.