# displaying tiff image within the browser using Iframe

Tags: java

I am displaying pdf image using following code in a jsp file:

```
showcaflink="ImageGet?ImagePath="+ImagePath+"'";

<a href='"+showcaflink+"' id='autoshowcaf' onclick='hideMe()' target='myIframe' class='content3' style='font-family:Verdana; color:#06C; text-decoration:none; font-size:12px;></a>

//using iframe as

<iframe src="" name="myIframe" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0" style="visibility:hidden; overflow:auto;" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

It is working fine for pdf images but not working tiff images that is always downloading. Any suggestions? it is in java

Comment: Did you meant Java or Javascript? Both looks similar but it is not the same!

Answer (score 0):

Displaying PDF is browser's capability. If you use older versions of browsers even pdf files will get downloaded.

Comment: but i want displaying tiff image but not download

Comment: @Mohammed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser confirms Aruns answer.