# HTML image is not loading?

Tags: html, image, screen-grab

I have trouble loading a html img `<img src="tour1.tiff">`. There is no error from the console. When I tried loading another img, it loads, but this "tour.tiff" does not. I suspect it is because I got the image from Mac's Grab application. I selected a part of the screen to "grab" and saved it as tour1.tiff .

Why is this image not loading, how do I make it load? Please state in the comments if I need to be clearer.

Comment: Look here, on SO, ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser

Comment: @nelek Even after I converted the .tiff into a .png and a .jpg, it still does not load.

Comment: and console still print no errors?

Comment: @deniskoronets there still is no error in chrome console.

Comment: try to clean browser cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved this problem.

- I first opened the .tiff file in the Mac Preview application.
- Then I duplicated the file.
- I saved the duplicate in .png format.

And the image finally loads in the webpage.