# How to display an image of type TIFF?

Tags: html, image, tiff, preview

I need to do a preview of tiff files.
I need a alternative to services google using iframe..

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicated question: [Display TIFF image in all web browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser)

Answer (score 0):

I believe displaying tiff is a matter of browser support (or if the browser has the plugin for it).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Depending on where you get your images, you might be able ask them to generate the image in a different format (like jpg, png, etc).