# Cross-platform/browser .tiff web viewer

Tags: cross-browser, cross-platform, tiff, viewer, browser-plugin

I'm trying to find a browser plugin or something like that to view/rotate/zoom/etc. multiple paged .tiff files. My requirements are that it must be cross-platform (Windows, Linux, ...) and cross-browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE, ...). The closest related topic I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser), and almost everywhere points to [AlternaTIFF](http://www.alternatiff.com/), but it doesn't work in Linux.

Where can I find such plugin or is there anyway I can manipulate .tiff files via web browser?

Comment: I would convert the tiff into jpg server side and view *that*, much easier and more reliable

Comment: I don't know if that would work for multiple paged files @Pekka웃

Comment: Oh, sure. ImageMagick can convert each page of a tiff into a jpeg, easy. You'd have to use a gallery of some sort to allow the user to browse through them - but that's still likely orders of magnitude easier to do than a cross-platform TIFF viewer.

Comment: The current "standard solution" is to send JPEG renderings of each "view" of the TIFF file across the internet to a browser. This is slow, wasteful of bandwidth/compute resources and less than ideal. My attempts to push back on this idea with a client side TIFF viewer have failed. The strange thing is that a PDF viewer is an order of magnitude more complicated to write, yet can be found for every browser.