# Is there any way to show TIFF Image in browser?

Tags: browser, tiff

I need to show tiff images in browser. Is there any way to show multi page tiff in browser?

Any addon or plugins that displays?
Any alternative that shows tiff without converting it to other formats ?

Comment: It seems that Safari is the only (mainstream) browser that supports tiff:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support. You can find more details on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser

Answer (score 1):

As Iza mentioned in the comment above, the functionality for loading a TIF image in a browser is a limitation of the browser support itself. It does appear that Safari is the only "mainstream" browser that supports displaying TIF images:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

The only options for achieving this functionality with all browsers would be to either convert your TIF images into a MIME type that all browsers support in a back end service or perform a batch convert operation on all your TIF images. There are a variety of libraries that you can use to maintain the quality and data of your tiff during conversion.