# which image formats are possible for image tags?

Tags: html

Do `<img>` tags support tiff image formats? Is there any way to include a tiff image to a webpage using an HTML document?

I have tried it normally using the general syntax of the `<img>` tag but it is not working.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser

Answer (score 1):

It will probably only work in Safari as the last time I checked, safari was the only mainstream browser that supported Tiffs.