# How do I view Tiff images in HTML5?

Tags: html, image, view, tiff

HTML5 supports JPEG and PNG image formats, but TIFF is not supported. How do open a TIFF image in an HTML5 page?

Answer (score 1):

Tiff image format is not supported by the browser.

However, if you search the linked site, you can find the answer

https://github.com/iwscoop/iws.loader

It seems to be a site that provides image viewer in HTML5 for free.

I hope you have a good result.

Answer (score 0):

TIFF image support is varying see here:

[Display TIFF image in all web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser)

Here is a good but out-dated website for TIFF images on webpages:

http://www.alternatiff.com/howtoembed.html

If that doesn't work try using a converter (Maybe something like this....)

http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg

Hope this Helps.