# Is it possible to show TIF/TIFF images in chrome/IE?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, tiff

I got `JS` code which currently shows images like: `jpg, bmp, gif.`

By given requirement, I also need to show `TIF` & `TIFF` images.

We mostly using `Chrome` and `IE` but not `Safari` which taking care of `TIFF` files and showing them without any extension, I also saw that there are several extensions for `Chrome` which solve this issue perfectly.

I'm trying to have an update to my JS code in order to show these files, without any extension, I would like to include some extension code in my JS or any other code is welcome.

Other out of the box solutions can come into consideration.

Comment: why do you need js to show image files?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176991/display-tiff-image-in-all-web-browser

Comment: it's `JS` using `JSP` which is mainly `html`

Comment: https://github.com/seikichi/tiff.js

Comment: For IE, You not need any special code. A simple JS code can also display TIF images. You can refer example here. https://textuploader.com/deit2 Here you can see the output in IE. https://i.postimg.cc/0Q9Q7sxd/85.gif